# Logistic regression error Object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: python, classification

I was training a logistic classifier and after calling the classifier, I can't seem to be able to fit the training data. Here is what I'm getting.

```py
# calling the classifier 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# instantiated the classifier
log model = LogisticRegression()

# when I try to fit the model with
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I get this error

```sh
------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-0b508b2e1562> in <module>
----> 1 logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1340             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
   1341 
-> 1342         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype,
   1343                                    order="C",
   1344                                    accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute '_validate_data'
```

can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

to

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
```

and instantiate the classifier using

```
log_model = lm.LogisticRegression()
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. But It didn't fix it. I still get the same error.

Comment: i faced almost similar problem but it solved my issue. Sorry to know didn't work for you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks a lot for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you aren't using *log model* instead of *logmodel* to instantiate the the **LogisticRegression** method.